# calculation between consecutive rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with following structure and I need to do calculation (say subtraction) between 2 consecutive dates (given the dates available) and insert rows in the bottom to count numbers of 0’s in the columns post-calculation, and calculate percentage of the 0's.

The main problem I have is the dates are random: length is random, not necessary in order (I had problem to do “order by” in a temp table within another “select” statement, so… I left it as not sorted, please help), and not necessary complete (eg: missing 2015-01-04 in the example)
Column lengths are random: not necessary stop at “group 3” as in the example.

```
Date        group1  group2  group3...
2015-01-01  1       2       3
2015-01-05  1       1       NULL
2015-01-03  2       2       3
2015-01-04  3       4       1
```

The calculation needs to be done is as following:

```
Date        group1  group2  group3...
2015-01-01  1-2     2-2     3-3
2015-01-03  2-3     2-4     3-1
2015-01-04  3-1     4-1     1-NULL
```

The final table need to be:

```
Date        group1  group2  group3...
2015-01-01  -1      0       0
2015-01-03  -1      -2       2
2015-01-04  2       3       NULL
count-zero  0       1       1
zero-perc   0       33.33   33.33
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [LEAD](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213125.aspx) windowed function:

```
select
    Date,
    group1 - LEAD(group1) over(order by Date) as group1,
    group1 - LEAD(group2) over(order by Date) as group2,
    group1 - LEAD(group3) over(order by Date) as group3...
from YourTable
```

To do it dynamically, use `sys.tables` and `sys.columns` to build your query:

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max) = ''
select @sql = 'select Date,' + 
    (select c.name + ' - LEAD(' + c.name + ') over(order by Date) as ' + c.name +
        case row_number() over(order by c.column_id desc)
            when 1 then '' else ',' end
     from sys.columns c
     where object_id = t.object_id
         and c.name like 'group%'
     order by c.column_id asc
     for xml path('')) + ' from YourTable'
from sys.tables t
where t.name = 'YourTable'

exec(@sql)
```

Comment: what if I have over hundreds groups (over hundreds dates as well). Do I need to write the LEAD statement hundreds times? Is there any dynamic way to do it?

Not sure if it would be easier to work on un-pivot table, so the original data looked like: data column, a category column (containing the group1, or group2, etc information) and a number column.

Answer (score 0):

The classical approach is to number the rows and then join them via consecutive numbers. Your system may have other options though:

```
with OrderedData as (
    select
        t1.*,
        /* assigned sequential numbers to the rows */
        (select count(*) from T as t2 where t2.Date <= t1.Date) as DateNumber,

        /* in sql server this may be preferable to a subquery */
        -- row_number() over (order by Date) as DateNumber

        /* finding the next date is another option that might seem clearer */
        (select min(t2.Date) from T as t2 where t2.Date > t1.Date) as NextDate
    from T as t1
)
select od1.Date, od2.group1 - od1.group1, od2.group2 - od1.group2, od2.group3 - od1.group3
from OrderedData as od1
    left outer join OrderedData as od2
        /* match up consecutive rows */
        on od2.DateNumber = od1.DateNumber + 1
```

This doesn't handle your zero rows though.

Comment: Thanks. Anyway to do the "od2.groupx-od1.groupx" dynamically? I need to run the same code over hundreds tables, and each of them may have different numbers of groups...

Comment: No, I don't think there's a clean way to do that. You're probably looking at using a query like above as a template and then generating all your queries by looking at system tables or information_schema. That's an entirely different question from the one you posed.

Comment: Ya. That's different issue. I just want to know if there is way to not explicitly write that subtraction statement hundreds times. Like there is way to dynamically pivot a table without hardcoding every single pivoted columns. But not sure if it's do-able in this case.

Comment: Does this help?

;with Pivoted ([data()]) as ( 
    select 'od2.' + c.COLUMN_NAME + ' - ' + 'od1.' + c.COLUMN_NAME + ' as ' + c.COLUMN_NAME + ', '
    from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS as c
    where c.TABLE_NAME = '<MYTABLENAME>' and c.COLUMN_NAME like 'group%'
    order by c.TABLE_NAME, c.ORDINAL_POSITION
    for xml path(''), type
), 
XmlRawData (csv) AS ( 
    select (select [data()] as mydata from Pivoted as d for xml raw, type).value( '/row[1]/mydata[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') as csv
) 
select left(csv, len(csv)-1) as ExpressionList from XmlRawData